# Mouse navigation showing some white page symbols

Tags: 20.04, settings, appearance

I selected `Large Text` option in `seeing` of Universal Access in Ubuntu settings.

After selecting it, whenever I move my mouse, it is showing some small blank page symbols floating along with mouse. It is inconvenient to see.

Is it possible to stop them appearing?

Answer (score 0):

Such page symbols are due to the activation of the `zoom` option.

After deselecting that option, mouse navigation does not create any symbols.